# How to fetch attribute value from database and apply to form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get the background-color for forms from the user and storing the value in user_preference table and applying those back-ground color by fetching data from table into the same form.

My forms look like this:

```
<%= form_for @user_preference do |u|%>
 <p>
    <%= u.label :title %><br>
    <%= u.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :description %><br>
    <%= u.text_field :description %>
  </p>

  <p> <%= u.label :back_ground_color %><br>
    <%= u.select :bgcolor, options_for_select(UserPreference.bgcolor_options) %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :font %><br>
    <%= u.select :font, options_for_select(UserPreference.font_options) %>

  </p>

 <br >
  <p>
    <%= u.submit %>
  </p>
  <div style="<%= 'background-color:#{@user_preference.bgcolor};' %>"</style></div>
  <hr >
<% end %>
```

I am rendering this form again after saving the value in database, is this the way to do ?

here is my controller:

```
class UserPreferencesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user_preference = UserPreference.new
    end

    def create
        @user_preference = UserPreference.new(user_pref_params)
        @user_preference.user = current_user
        @user_preference.save if user_signed_in?
        render 'user_preferences/new'
    end
```

Is it the correct way of doing...
let me know where I am doing mistake, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Obviously `@user_preference.bgcolor` will be blank for a new record, possibly giving you an error.

Comment: No I am not getting any error, because I am rendering the new.html.erb after saving the value in database. I dont know whether my approach is correct or not, how to achieve it ?

Comment: Perhaps you should let the users preview the changes first using js before letting they submit the form.

Comment: @bodyfarmer Could you please let me know the approach to check for preview

Comment: Do you want to change the color of background as per User created the last UserPreference? I agree with @bodyfarmer : you should let the users preview the changes first

Comment: yes, I want to use the color which user has given in last UserPreference

Comment: @cyborg: I have post the answer. please check it and let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: sure, give me sometime !! I am trying one more approach, and will use your approach also, btw thanks for you time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to fetch the last data and according it change the background-color then you have to pass the object while rendering new form:

Change in your controller's new method (EDIT: FIXED Typo in UserPreference ):

```
def new
  @user_preference = UserPreference.new
  @last_bgcolor = UserPreference.last.bgcolor #this will fetch the last data and return last bgcolor entered
 end
```

To apply that background-color to form only add `div` tag in your template above `form_for`:

```
<div style="background-color:<%= @last_bgcolor %>"> 
 <%= form_for @user_preference do |u|%>
  .....
  #your form code
 <% end %>
</div>  #close the div after your form_for closed by <% end %>
```

In case of `@last_bgcolor` returns `nil` then you will see the default form's background-color.

If you want that while selecting color user can preview before submit the data then I have implement sample demo. Check this **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaganGami/xt3xv/158/)**

Comment: @cyborg : Glad to know it helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the last saved background you need to find the record first. In your controller:

```
 def new
        @user_preference = UserPreference.new
        # Find the last record 
        @last_preference = UserPrefrence.find(insert_your_params_here)
 end
```

And update your view:

```
<div style="<%= 'background-color:#{@last_preference.bgcolor};' %>"</style></div>
```

After that, you may decide to add [this script](http://jsfiddle.net/8EMef/) to your form for more usability.